# Java error "Array required, but String found" while importing text file

Tags: java, arrays, string, import, stringbuilder

I'm trying to import a tab delimited text file into an 2D array but when trying to assign the values of the splitted String into the array I get the error "Array required, but String found".

Here is my code so far:

```
try {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader ("Laberinto.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    
    String s,str;
    String[] buffer;
    
    int y=0;
    
    while ((s=br.readLine())!= null){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        str=builder.append(s).toString();
        buffer=str.split("\t");
        
        for (int x=0;x<str.length();x++){
            this.lab[x][y]=Integer.parseInt(str[x]);
        }

        y++;
    }
}
```

I get the error on the line `this.lab[x][y]=Integer.parseInt(str[x]);`.

The file is basically a bunch of 1s and 0s that form a labyrinth (1 being the walls and 0 the corridors) delimited by tabulator.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't even see that you have initialized your array.

Comment: Please remove your useless `StringBuilder` and use `buffer=s.split("\t")` first. Your code is too obfuscated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str` is a string - a line from your input... That's not what you wanted.

You need to parse your `buffer`:

```
for (int x=0;x<buffer.length();x++){
     this.lab[x][y]=Integer.parseInt(buffer[x]);
}
```

Comment: OH **** your right im such an idiot this is what i get for coding  this late at night thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> `parseInt(str[x])`

You can't use array subscripts: `[]`, to index into a `String`, and obviously `str` is a `String`.
For a solution you might want to consider using [`charAt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) and then [`String.valueOf(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-char-), which will convert the `char` back in case you need it.

Comment: im actually trying to assign the value to the array lab not to str D:

Comment: Never mind i know what i did wrong i should've parsed my buffer not str - thats what i get for coding this late at night lol thank you anyways

Answer (score 1):

You declared str as follows:

```
  String s,str;
```

and tried to use it as follows:

```
  this.lab[x][y]=Integer.parseInt(str[x]);
```

The declaration declares it as a `String`.  The usage (see the RHS of the `=` !!) tries to use it as an array of `String`.

---

Actually, I think your real error is that you are attempting to parse the wrong thing.  I think it should probably be this:

```
  buffer=str.split("\t");
  for (int x=0;x<buffer.length;x++){
      this.lab[x][y]=Integer.parseInt(buffer[x]);
  }
```

Comment: yeah your right i messed up lol! thats what i get for coding this late at night lol

Comment: And your punctuation and grammar is suffering too.  That should be "you're" not "your" :-)

Comment: yup, as i said it's really late here I think i'll continue coding in the morning before i embarrass myself more